# Value in SharedPreferences is not updated in splash screen

Tags: android

I am trying to manage my connection status by SharedPreferences, so i created a Session Manager which holding some values and 1 of them is the connection value under the key :"Constants.TAG_CONNECTED" . but when i do a logout the value in this variable stay as true instead become false and i don't know why.
when i print inside the logoutUser function the status i get it false but when i begin my splash screen i get the value again is true.

this is my session manager code:

```
public class SessionManager  {

    private static SessionManager sessionManagerInstance = null;
    // Shared Preferences reference
    SharedPreferences pref;
    // Editor reference for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    // Context
    Context _context;
    private boolean isConnected = false;

    public static SessionManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(sessionManagerInstance == null)
        {
            sessionManagerInstance = new SessionManager(context);
        }
        return sessionManagerInstance;
    }

    private SessionManager(Context context)
    {
        this._context=context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFER_NAME,Constants.PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
        StoreUserSession("false", Constants.TAG_CONNECTED);
    }

    public void StoreUserSession(String val,String Key ){
        editor.putString(Key, val);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public HashMap<String,String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();

        user.put(Constants.TAG_EMAIL, pref.getString(Constants.TAG_EMAIL, null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_NAME, pref.getString(Constants.TAG_NAME, null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_MOB,pref.getString(Constants.TAG_MOB,null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_PASS, pref.getString(Constants.TAG_PASS, null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_GEN, pref.getString(Constants.TAG_GEN, null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_USERID,pref.getString(Constants.TAG_USERID,null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_AGE,pref.getString(Constants.TAG_AGE,null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_IMG,pref.getString(Constants.TAG_IMG,null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_REGID,pref.getString(Constants.TAG_REGID,null));
        user.put(Constants.TAG_CONNECTED,pref.getString(Constants.TAG_CONNECTED,null));

        return user;
    }

    public void logoutUser(){
        //clean pref
        //editor.clear();
        //editor.commit();
        //this.isConnected = false;
        StoreUserSession("false",Constants.TAG_CONNECTED);
        editor.apply();
        Log.d("user connection",getUserDetails().get(Constants.TAG_CONNECTED).toString());
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return isConnected;
    }
    public void setIsConnected(boolean isConnected) {

        this.isConnected = isConnected;
    }
}
```

my splash screen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    private SessionManager sm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        sm = SessionManager.getInstance(this);
        final boolean is_coonected = sm.getUserDetails().get(Constants.TAG_CONNECTED).equals("false");
        Log.d("is connected",String.valueOf(is_coonected));


        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Connection Error")
                    .setMessage("Internet seems to be broken")
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                              android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                              System.exit(0);
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.error_32)
                    .show();

        }else {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                    if(!sm.isConnected()) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainScreen.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * function that check if the internet services is available in case not application will be terminated
     * @return false-in case internet is not available
     */
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected =  activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        return  isConnected;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to move your editor.apply in your method StoreUserSession(String val,String Key ) after the commit

Comment: You should check anywhere you set `Constants.TAG_CONNECTED` to `"true"`,when you take value from sp,you set the default value to `null`,so if you get true value,I think maybe you set the value to "true" somewhere.

Comment: i found the problem each time that the application boot the constructor of the session manager creating new instance so indie that i initialize the value to false. do you know if there is a way to overcome this issue? i thought that the SharedPreferences stay alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your comments its helped me i just edited this line:
if(getUserDetails().get(Constants.TAG_CONNECTED) == null)
            StoreUserSession("false", Constants.TAG_CONNECTED);